# Basic issue binding view to a DateTime property. Better luck with DateTime nullable, but why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has two input fields that are bound to a DateTime and a DateTime? (nullable DateTime) model property.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtEffectiveDate", Value = Model.EffectiveDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @class = "form-control " } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CancelDate, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CancelDate, new {htmlAttributes = new {id = "txtCancelDate", @class = "form-control " } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CancelDate, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the two properties of the Model:

```
    public class Edit
    {
        [Display(Name = "Effective Date")]        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Cancel Date")]
        [NotEqualTo("EffectiveDate")]
        [IsGreaterThan(otherProperty:"EffectiveDate", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be after {1}")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]         
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, NullDisplayText = "")]
        public DateTime? CancelDate { get; set; }

        --etc
   }
```

Both fields are required, so I originally did not see a need for a Nullable DateTime data type. However, I'm finding that if I were to use the DateTime data type, I am getting unexpected behavior.

For example, if the user types in 11/32/2016 for either the Effective or Cancel Date fields, a client side validation error is displayed "The field Effective Date must be a date" and "The field Cancel Date must be a date." However, if the user types in 11/31/2016 for both values, the property attribute-driven client side validation does not catch this and the invalid dates are posted to the server as 1/1/0001 for the regular not nullable EffectiveDate property's value and *NULL* for the nullable CancelDate property. I was disappointed in this apparent shortcoming in what I would have expected to be a basic common edit, but things get worse when we post to the controller method...

Since client side validation logic wasn't good enough to catch on the client that 11/31/2016 was not a valid date, it seems reasonable to me that since the EffectiveDate is a DateTime, it must be assign some value and 1/1/0001 seemed like a reasonable choice. Furthermore, since CancelDate was nullable, null is posted, as expected.

```
  In my controller, I check if the ModelState is invalid.

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Edit")]
        public ActionResult Edit(ViewModels.Edit modifiedAssessment)
        {
        if (!base.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
               return this.View(modifiedAssessment);
         }
```

The ModelState contains two errors which are displayed next to their associated input fields:

```
 The value '11/31/2017,07/22/2016 12:30:08' is not valid for Effective Date.   
 The value '11/31/2017' is not valid for Cancel Date.
```

Another issue:

Why are two dates, 11/31/2017 and 7/22/2016 (today), part of the error message for EffectiveDate?

Another troubling part is troubling part is that the Dates that now appear in the EffectiveDate and CancelDate input fields are now 01/01/0001 and 11/31/2017, respectively. Note that 11/31/2017 is not a valid value for either a dateTime or a DateTime? data type, yet the nullable CancelDate property did not wipe out the originally typed value but the EffectiveDate DateTime value did.

Given this behavior, how can anyone use the DateTime datatype for model binding? I tried to add the following attribute to the EffectiveDate DateTime property

```
 [DataType( DataType.Date)]
```

but this opens up a large can of worms when I consider all of the browsers that may be using the web app.

It seems like I must be missing something basic since surely binding us a DateTime should be very common. I'm brand new to MVC.

Comment: client side validation uses jquery val. Maybe that library did not check whether date is valid or not?

Comment: My bad. I had a copy and paste error where I bound a second field, Last Timestamp to the same EffectiveDate model property. I bound it to the proper property and all was well. Should I cancel this post?